# A good alternative to Opera 12.17? (with web browsing and native email client)

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, email-client

I am a long time Opera user, and in particular I really enjoyed the integrated mail client.

I have managed to successfully migrate all my emails to the "Opera Mail" standalone client released just before they had [a massive technology change](https://dev.opera.com/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit/) that forced them to remove [many useful features](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/comment/14867532) of the browser, including the email client, [angering](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1786592/why-did-opera-change-to-chrome-engine/p1) [a lot](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1831043/the-impending-demise-of-opera/p1) of people, including me.

Opera Mail has never been updated, and this is a big problem because it hangs a lot under Windows 7-10, especially with a large database holding thousands of emails (my opera folder is at 10gb now). One bad click and its window freezes (hangs) to death. After almost two years of crashes this has become unbearable.

So I'm here asking if anybody can recommend a proper replacement for Opera that has at least the UI flexibility of Opera and an integrated email client with a "all unread" email folder that contains emails from all accounts.

I'm aware that the Otter and Vivaldi projects exist, and afaik neither of them has yet implemented a working e-mail client.

I'm also aware that similar behaviors could be replicated by using Firefox/Chrome + a ton of extensions, but I'd rather prefer to have the same tight integration between the browser and email client that is present in Opera 12.x.

Bonus points if it is (natively) portable and has a toggle-able and customizable sidebar.

My hope is to be able to browse the web and read my emails with the same program because that is a workflow I came to enjoy in the past years.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has enough functionality, but would [Simple Mail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-mail/) work along with Firefox? I don't think one extension would be considered a FrankenBrowser:)

Comment: In the immediate time, you can upgrade to Opera 12.18, although I doubt it brings any improvements to the mail client. Vivaldi is just the same pure crap as Opera 15+ with a projected mail client and a more exotic UI. I think Otter Browser in the long run can take the place of the real Opera, but it's too unstable for now.

Comment: @Alejandro I have stability issues with both Opera 12.7 and the standalone Opera Mail. I don't know if it is related to the size of the mailboxes... I will try Opera 12.18 (I thought that 12.17 was the last one), maybe it fixes the crashes... however as an abandoned browser it won't last much.

Comment: What's wrong with chrome + gmail?  Two points: 1) Nothing is preventing you from using one program except for the number of choices, and 2) The fact that you've come to enjoy something in the past years does not *necessarily* mean its better.

Comment: @Menasheh I use Opera's email client as the central hub for all my email accounts. Not just for gmail.

Comment: @beppe9000 You can use gmail the same way.

Comment: @Menasheh I'd like for it to happen locally, not on Google's cloud servers

Answer (score 1):

When I see a question about tight integration of browser and email client, the solution that immediately springs to mind is [Seamonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/):

> Web-browser, advanced e-mail, newsgroup and feed client, IRC chat, and HTML editing made simple—all your Internet needs in one application.

From the project's own screenshots, here is the browser and email client, running in Win7:

[image: seamonkey browser]

[image: seamonkey email]

Whether it precisely satisfies some of the UI requirements, I'm not sure. I can imagine OP would want at least the [Speed Start plugin](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/seamonkey/addon/speed-start/), which provides the "speed-dial" functionality quite nicely.

> **OP:** Bonus points if it is portable and has a toggle-able and customizable sidebar.

- **Sidebar**: there is one, toggle-able (`F9`), but I don't know about customizable:

  [image: seamonkey sidebar]
- **Portable**: you can get the up-to-date portable version from [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/seamonkey_portable).

Comment: Does it still exist? I didn't know…

Comment: @wb9688 Yes, of course it still exists, and is actively developed. Did you follow the link at the top of the post? [Here it is again](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/). Hope that helps!